# AWS RDS SDK get instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to get the RDS instance role (reader or writer) using the AWS RDS Java SDK.

I tried the following api methods: `getReadReplicaSourceDBInstanceIdentifier()` and `getReadReplicaDBInstanceIdentifiers()`, but none of them ever returned anything else then

> null

or

> 0

Is there any other method to be used in order to determine if instance is reader or writer?

Thank you for your answers!